# Crear una carpeta con PHP desde un input y que incluya un archivo index.php

Tags: php, html

Necesito que al introducir, por ejemplo, **carlos1** en un campo `<input>` de texto, se cree automáticamente en el directorio una carpeta con ese nombre y que, además de eso, incluya un archivo `index.php` predeterminado.

Este es el código que llevo hasta ahora, pero me falta el archivo `index.php` predeterminado:

```
<form method="post">
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST["crear"])){
        mkdir($_POST["nombre"], 755);
    }
?>

<label>Nombre de la carpeta</label>
<input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" value="" />
<input type="submit" name="crear" id="crear" value="Crear" />
</form>
```

Lo logré de esa forma, intenté agregando lo siguiente para que tuviese cada carpeta un archivo `index.php`, pero aun no  lo he logrado:

```
$content = "<html><body><p>Lorem...<p/></body></html>"
file_put_contents('index.php', $contenido);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para poder hacer lo que quieres necesitas realizar dos tareas:

- Crear el directorio en el que crearás el archivo `index.php` si éste no existe.
- Crear el archivo `index.php` con los datos predeterminados.

El código debería ponerse al comienzo del script PHP para separar lo que verás en el navegador de lo que se ejecuta en el servidor y, además, evitarás tener la impresión de que ambas cosas se ejecutan paralelamente en el cliente.

Además, he hecho una comprobación básica mediante expresiones regulares con [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/preg_match) de cómo debe llamarse un directorio para evitar ataques al servidor creando directorios en el directorio padre o de sistema poniendo, por ejemplo, nombres como `/directorio`, `../directorio`, o bien crear directorios ocultos empezando el directorio con un punto como, por ejemplo, `.directorio_oculto`.

```
<?php 
if (empty($_POST['nombre']) === false) {
  /* El primer carácter sólo puede ser una letra o número, el resto pueden tener
      guiones bajos, medios y puntos */
  if (preg_match('/^[a-z0-9][a-z0-9_-.]+$/i', $_POST['nombre']) === 0) {
    $error = 'El nombre del directorio no es válido';
  } else {
    /* Si existe un archivo o directorio con ese nombre no lo sobreescribiremos */
    if (file_exists($_POST['nombre']) === true) {
      $error = 'El archivo o directorio ya existe';
    } else {
      if (@mkdir($_POST['nombre'], 755) === false) {
        $error = 'No se pudo crear el directorio';
      } else {
        $content = "<html><body><p>Lorem...<p/></body></html>";
        /* Concatenamos al nombre del directorio el nombre del archivo a crear */
        if (@file_put_contents($_POST['nombre'] . '/index.php', $contenido) === false) {
          $error = 'No se pudo crear el archivo index.php';
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
/* Si hubo un error lo mostramos */
if (empty($error) === false) {
  echo '<p style="color: red">', htmlspecialchars($error), '</p>', PHP_EOL;
}
?>
<form method="post" action="<?= htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) ?>">
  <label>Nombre de la carpeta</label>
  <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" value="" />
  <input type="submit" name="crear" id="crear" value="Crear" />
</form>
```

Comment: Muy bien amigo me sirvio correctamente pero tengo otro problema, al tratar de colocar un codigo html largo en $content = "CONTENIDO HTML";  me da error con solo abrir el archivo 

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'Content' (T_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\pagina\index.php on line 17`

Comment: Deberías crear una nueva pregunta con ese nuevo problema porque ya no tiene relación con la creación de un directorio enviado desde un formulario y para poder ayudar a otras personas con el mismo problema es mejor separar cada uno en una pregunta diferente. Cuando la crees mándame un comentario aquí mismo y voy a la nueva pregunta a echarle un vistazo. En ella deberías poner el código exacto que te genera problemas y no un simple y reducido `$content = "CONTENIDO HTML";` que no ayuda a saber qué te falla.

Comment: Listo amigo, ya habia creado el tema este es el enlace https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/279012/crear-archivo-index-desde-input-problema-con-el-contenido?noredirect=1#comment513087_279012

Answer (score 5):

Se envía como post y lo recibes.

```
$carpeta = '/ruta/carpeta';
if (!file_exists($carpeta)) {
    mkdir($carpeta, 0777, true);
    $content = "<html><body><p>Lorem...<p/></body></html>"
    file_put_contents('index.php', $contenido);
```

Comment: Hola amigo gracias por responder! he probado el codigo pero no funciona al darle al boton submit no crea la carpeta que podria ser?

Comment: Tienes que primero crear la variable que reciba al campo del formulario y en base a eso reemplazas lo necesario en el codigo que te pase.

Comment: Disculpa amigo, gracias por tu apoyo no me soy muy bueno manejando php me podrias ayduar con un ejemplo funcionando la verdad si no es mucha molestia y disculpame, lo estoy intentando de varias formas y aun no lo logro cree el form con el nombre y llamo al archivo php con el metodo post pero no me funciona

Comment: Amigo puedes leer la pregunta principal nuevamente actualice hace un momento para ver si me puedes ayudar