# Crear archivo index desde input problema con el contenido

Tags: php, html

Hola tengo este codigo con el cual puedo crear un archivo index en una carpeta desde un input

```
<?php $nombre = ($_GET['nombre']);
$archivo= "index.php";  
$contenido= "AQUI EL CODIGO HTML"; 
$fch= fopen(carpeta.'/'.$archivo, "w");
fwrite($fch, $contenido);  
fclose($fch);  
?>
```

Todo bien hasta aqui, el problema radica en que cuando inserto el codigo completo de la pagina en la parte que dice "AQUI EL CODIGO HTML" al ejecutarlo me da un error en php

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'http' (T_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\crear.php on line 10
```

Creo que es por el codigo de alguna forma esta tratando de leerlo o ejecutarlo, pero solo quiero que el archivo index.php tenga el codigo adentro y si no es posible de esta forma se podria por ejemplo tener un archivo index.php guardado en el directorio y entonces que la funcion lo que haga seria copiarlo y pegarlo en la nueva carpeta?

El codigo funciona 100% asi como esta escrito, al ejecutarlo crea el archivo index.php con el contenido adentro "AQUI EL CODIGO HTML" pero si quiero ingresar de verdad un codigo html largo me da error al crear el archivo

Espero su ayuda gracias.!

Comment: ¿Cual es la linea 10?

Comment: @JDev amigo la linea 10 es esta `$contenido= "AQUI EL CODIGO HTML"; ` aqui es donde coloco el codigo html largo que tengo guardado y me sale error

Comment: ¿Has escapado bien ese codigo html? Pon un ejemplo si puedes.

Comment: Debes compartir el contenido **exacto** de esa línea para poder reproducir tu problema ya que es debido a ella el error. Ponernos una versión reducida no nos ayuda a corregir el problema.

Comment: @OscarGarcia Disculpa amigo lo coloco de esa forma ya que el otro codigo es bastante largo, pero me gustaria no tener problemas al agregar cualquier codigo ahi.. `$content = "CONTENIDO HTML";`  la otra opcion seria tener ya el archivo index.php guardado y que una funcion en php solo lo copie de un directorio y lo pegue en el directorio nuevo.. cual opcion es mas viable?

Comment: Es que el problema está, precisamente, en que has introducido mal el HTML. Lo más probable es que no estés escapando las comillas dobles que están en el interior del HTML, por lo que PHP se piensa que ha finalizado la cadena y que lo siguiente que llega es código PHP (y, tú estás introduciendo más HTML).

Comment: El codigo seria el index de esta pagina www.vespacio.com

Comment: ¿Un copiar/pegar de ese código HTML? No te funcionará si usar algo que escape las comillas dobles, por eso no te funciona correctamente. Si no quieres complicarte mucho la vida puedes usar una web que escape cadenas a JSON (que son compatibles con las cadenas PHP) como el que te ofrece [https://www.freeformatter.com/json-escape.html](https://www.freeformatter.com/json-escape.html). Pega allí el HTML y luego pulsa en **ESCAPE**. El resultado podrás pegarlo dentro de una cadena entre comillas dobles en PHP. Aunque debes recordar que las variables (`$esta` por ejemplo) serán interpretadas.

Comment: @OscarGarcia gracias amigo ya lo estare acomodando!

Comment: Olvida mi comentario anterior, he encontrado un par de ellas que generan el código en PHP llamando a [`addslashes()`](http://php.net/addslashes) que te funcionarán mejor usando comillas simples (para evitar interpretación de variables): http://addslashes.onlinephpfunctions.com/ y https://www.tools4noobs.com/online_php_functions/addslashes/

Comment: @OscarGarcia amigo lo he hecho y funciona todo bien pero solo tengo un ultimo problema, en el codigo html hay un pequeñisimo fragmento de codigo php el cual es este `<?php
$texto = file_get_contents('datos.txt'); 
$texto = nl2br($texto); 
echo $texto
?>` pero entonces al agregarlo me lo transforma a este `<?php
 = file_get_contents('datos.txt'); 
 = nl2br(); 
echo 
?>` causando un error

Comment: Ese codigo solo hace ver un archivo .txt externo y mostrarlo en la pagina, el problema es que es PHP conoces alguna forma de mostrar el mismo .txt pero con html o no se si javascript podria funcionar

Comment: Listo amigo ya esta solucionado disculpa, solo utilice este codigo `<?php echo file_get_contents('datos.txt'); ?>`